Structure model for a first-order language formula
Let A is a first-order language formula as follow
$\forall x\left(P\left(x\right)\Rightarrow Q\left(x\right)\right)\wedge \exists x\left(R\left(x\right)\wedge Q\left(x\right)\right)\wedge 
\forall x\left(S\left(x\right)\Rightarrow R\left(x\right)\right)\Rightarrow \exists x
\left(P\left(x\right)\wedge S\left(x\right)\right)$
(1) Structure model $M_{1}=\left(M_{1},I_{1},\sigma_{1}\right)$ let $A_{M_{1}\left(\sigma\right)}=T$
(2)Structure model $M_{2}=\left(M_{2},I_{2},\sigma_{2}\right)$ let $A_{M_{2}\left(\sigma\right)}=F$
There's a certain way to solve this problem? I really have no ideal how to find model.Can anyone give me help to adress the question?

The easy part is (2): to falsify a formula you need a model $M$  with at least an element $a$  such that the antecedent of the formula is True and the consequent is False.
To falsify $∃x(P(x) ∧ S(x))$ means that if the element $a$ is P, then it cannot be S
and vice-versa. So, assuming $a ∈ P^M$, by $∀x(P(x) → Q(x))$ we have also $a ∈ Q^M$.
The part $∃x(R(x) ∧ Q(x))$ can be satisfied using again $a$. Finally, we have $∀x(S(x) → R(x))$  that is vacuously satisfied by the fact that $a ∉ S^M$.
In this way, you have $M_2$; you can use the machinery above to easily maufacture $M_1$.
